# Capturing Status Change Information for a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with >90000 rows of the form:

```
Student_Group_Number      Status            Date
Group1                    Public            26-Sep-21
Group1                    Public            27-Sep-21
Group1                    Public            29-Sep-21
Group2                    Public            10-Sep-21
Group2                    ABC - Private     15-Sep-21
Group2                    DEF - Private     19-Sep-21
Group3                    Public            06-Sep-21
Group3                    Public            17-Sep-21
Group3                    P - Private       18-Sep-21
Group4                    L - Private       02-Sep-21
Group4                    3 - Private       09-Sep-21
Group4                    X - Private       13-Sep-21
```

I want to find 'when' the status of a group changed from Public to anything else and have the output in the format:

```
Student_Group_Number      Date_change
Group1                    
Group2                    15-Sep-21
Group3                    18-Sep-21
Group4                    02-Sep-21
```

I spent some time on SO searching for 'status change capture' questions but I am not getting anything substantial. Given that I might also need to translate the Date_change to the original dataframe, I have been reading up on `groupby` command as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) per groups, replace first `NaN`s by `Public`, compare by `Public` and chained mask by not matched `Public`, convert not matche values to `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with aggregate first non NaN by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) (if exist):

```
m = (df.groupby('Student_Group_Number')['Status'].shift(fill_value='Public').eq('Public') &
       df['Status'].ne('Public'))


df = (df.assign(d = df['Date'].where(m))
        .groupby(['Student_Group_Number'])['d']
        .first()
        .reset_index(name='Date_change'))
print (df)
  Student_Group_Number Date_change
0               Group1        None
1               Group2   15-Sep-21
2               Group3   18-Sep-21
3               Group4   02-Sep-21
```

Comment: My dataset is very big and I am getting this error: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` when I execute the line with where(m).

Comment: @Nilima - Answer was edited, alternative solution, can you test?

Comment: What's `['d']` in the df = line? I have no columns named d.

Comment: @jezarael Getting the same error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @Nilima - Is possible use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` beefore my solution?

Comment: Included that line too - Same error. I am not sure why.

Comment: @Nilima - Are real data confidental?

Comment: Yes. :( They are confidential uni data.